# How to unify the space width in different browsers

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, non-breaking-characters

The space `&nbsp;` shows different width in Chrome and IE, how to unify them?

In IE it is shorter than in Chrome and Firefox.

I've tried use the font but nothing seems to have happened.

```
<span style="font-family: 宋体, SimSun; font-size: 20px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
```

Comment: Maybe we should use tables to indent the line instead of spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add padding in css to add a similar amount of space in span across various browsers.

Try to refer example below.

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <title>demo</title>
<style>
 span.padd{padding-left:60px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<span class="padd">Demo Text</span>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a good way for progrogrammer, but As we are using a html editor, that we can not edit the style like  padding

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `&nbsp;` as a separator between two elements, for exactly this reason.

Instead, you're better off setting the CSS `width:` attribute on the `<span>` to the exact width you need:

```
<span style="width: 10px"></span>
```

Note: I only show `px` here so the syntax is correct. You should pick a better unit of measure. See [this](https://medium.com/@julienetienne/pixels-are-dead-faa87cd8c8b9).

Frankly, even that's not a great solution. It would probably be better to put margin on the things that you need to separate, than to put a separator between them.